# How to round float to certain amount of decimal places Python

Tags: python, math, rounding

I have a randomly generated float from the random library, and I want to shorten it to any number of places, based on some other number.

Example:

input = 4.06098152

*processing the number, rounding to thousandths place*

output = 4.061

How would I do this?

Comment: ```print(round(float(input),3))```?

Comment: Realize that even with perfect rounding, some decimal numbers can't be exactly represented as `real`: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987)

Comment: I'm curious what you found when you searched for "python rounding".

Comment: @MarkRansom Not much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in `round` function:
The second argument in the paranthesis gives the amount of digits to round off

```
x=input("Enter a decimal number: ")
print(round(float(x),3))
```